# Spring Boot Config at Git

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-configuration

I am following an blog :

https://github.com/jeroenbellen/blog-manage-and-reload-spring-properties

I am developing the services using spring boot and I want to change the config at run-time without application restart.

I have run the code mentioned in the above github repo.
What I am not able to understand how does the example-service knows about config-service. There is nothing in code which link them together.

Also, there is just one example service but I have 10s of such example service, how do I use just one config service for all example services

Comment: What do you mean when you say "how does the example-service knows about config-service". Had a quick look at the git repo and I don't see the example or config service invoke each other. Aren't they both independent microservices?

Comment: @Jay no, that's the cool thing about Spring Cloud Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question

> **how does the example-service knows about config-service?**

**Short answer**

Magic happen when you add `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency

**Long answer** [from spring cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_client_side_usage)

> **Client Side Usage**
>
> To use these features in an application, just build it as a Spring
>   Boot application that depends on spring-cloud-config-client (e.g. see
>   the test cases for the config-client, or the sample app). The most
>   convenient way to add the dependency is via a Spring Boot starter
>   org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config. There is also a
>   parent pom and BOM (spring-cloud-starter-parent) for Maven users and a
>   Spring IO version management properties file for Gradle and Spring CLI
>   users.

Second question

> **Also, there is just one example service but I have 10s of such example**
>   **service, how do I use just one config service for all example services**

You just have to add `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency to each service. All services will look for config-service on http://localhost:8888 8888 being the default port

Comment: If I use multiple service , all using spring-cloud-config-client, then all the projects must be using different application.properties, then how do I define it?

Comment: You have only to add `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency to each service. No additional configs are required.

Answer (score 1):

The default is `http://localhost:8888` which is enough for this example, but might differ from your needs in a productive environment :)

You can configure the config server URI in `bootstrap.yml` (or `bootstrap.properties`) using the key `spring.cloud.config.uri`.

The `bootstrap` configuration file is evaluated first, so that you can set the actual properties using the config server.

Documentation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#config-first-bootstrap